# Parameter dependencies in Python - can't make it work

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to add a parameter dependency to my script. The idea is that *--clone* argument will require non-empty *--gituser*.

After perusing [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879657/argparse-argument-dependency), I tried the following

```
In [93]: class CloneAction(argparse.Action):
    ...:     def __call__(self, parser, namespace, _):
    ...:         if not namespace.git_user and namespace.clone:
    ...:             parser.error('"--clone" requires legal git user')
    ...:             
In [94]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [95]: parser.add_argument('-g', '--gituser', dest='git_user', type=str, default='', action=CloneAction)
Out[95]: CloneAction(option_strings=['-g', '--gituser'], dest='git_user', nargs=None, const=None, default='', type=<type 'str'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [96]: parser.add_argument('--clone', action='store_true', default=False)
Out[96]: _StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--clone'], dest='clone', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

Alas, it did not work

```
In [97]: parser.parse_args(['--clone'])
Out[97]: Namespace(clone=True, git_user='')
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you please include your implementation of `CloneAction`?

Comment: Also, note that the `--clone` action is just `_StoreTrueAction`, which won't check for any dependencies. You'd have to use a special action type *there* to check it, as there is no `-g` argument passed in triggering the `CloneAction` being checked.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ooops, missed that. Added. Do I need to define custom actions for both parameters?

Comment: That depends; is it an error to provide `--gituser` if no `--clone` has been set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This kind of inter argument dependency is easier to implement **after** parsing.

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if not namespace.git_user and namespace.clone:
    parser.error('"--clone" requires legal git user')
```

At that point, both `git_user` and `clone` have been parsed, and have their final values.

As you implemented it, the custom action is run only when there's a `--gituser` argument.  So I think it will raise the error when you give it `--gituser` without `--clone`.

You could give `--clone` a similar custom action, but it would also have to handle the `store_true` details.  And what should happen with the `--clone --gituser value` sequence?  The `clone` action will be run before the `gituser` value has been parsed.  Tests like this run into some tough argument order problems.

A couple of other issues:

- your custom action does not store any value, regardless of error not.  It's better to customize the `store` subclass.
- custom actions should raise `argparse.ArgumentError` rather than call `parser.error` directly.

The unittest file, `test/test_argparse.py` has an example of custom actions with mutual tests like this.  But it's just a toy, verifying that such code is allowed.

==================

You could, in theory, implement a `--clone` action that sets the `required` attribute of the `--gituser` Action.  That way, if `--gituser` is not used, the final `required` actions test of `parse_args` will raise an error.  But that requires saving a reference to the Action displayed in `out[95]` (or finding that in the `parse._actions` list.  Feasible but messy.

===================

Here's an example of a pair of interacting custom action classes from `test/test_argparse.py`.

```
class OptionalAction(argparse.Action):

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, value, option_string=None):
        try:
            # check destination and option string
            assert self.dest == 'spam', 'dest: %s' % self.dest
            assert option_string == '-s', 'flag: %s' % option_string
            # when option is before argument, badger=2, and when
            # option is after argument, badger=<whatever was set>
            expected_ns = NS(spam=0.25)
            if value in [0.125, 0.625]:
                expected_ns.badger = 2
            elif value in [2.0]:
                expected_ns.badger = 84
            else:
                raise AssertionError('value: %s' % value)
            assert expected_ns == namespace, ('expected %s, got %s' %
                                              (expected_ns, namespace))
        except AssertionError:
            e = sys.exc_info()[1]
            raise ArgumentParserError('opt_action failed: %s' % e)
        setattr(namespace, 'spam', value)
```

`NS` is a shorthand for `argparse.Namespace`.

```
class PositionalAction(argparse.Action):

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, value, option_string=None):
        try:
            assert option_string is None, ('option_string: %s' %
                                           option_string)
            # check destination
            assert self.dest == 'badger', 'dest: %s' % self.dest
            # when argument is before option, spam=0.25, and when
            # option is after argument, spam=<whatever was set>
            expected_ns = NS(badger=2)
            if value in [42, 84]:
                expected_ns.spam = 0.25
            elif value in [1]:
                expected_ns.spam = 0.625
            elif value in [2]:
                expected_ns.spam = 0.125
            else:
                raise AssertionError('value: %s' % value)
            assert expected_ns == namespace, ('expected %s, got %s' %
                                              (expected_ns, namespace))
        except AssertionError:
            e = sys.exc_info()[1]
            raise ArgumentParserError('arg_action failed: %s' % e)
        setattr(namespace, 'badger', value)
```

They are used in

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s', dest='spam', action=OptionalAction,
        type=float, default=0.25)
parser.add_argument('badger', action=PositionalAction,
        type=int, nargs='?', default=2)
```

And supposed to work with:

```
'-s0.125' producing: NS(spam=0.125, badger=2)),
'42',                NS(spam=0.25, badger=42)),
'-s 0.625 1',        NS(spam=0.625, badger=1)),
'84 -s2',            NS(spam=2.0, badger=84)),
```

This is an example of the kind of cross checking that can be done.  But I'll repeat that generally interactions are best handled after parsing, not during.

As to the implementation question - if the user does not give you `--gituser`, your custom Action is never called.  The `Action.__call__` of an `optional` is only used when that argument is used.  `positionals` are always used, but not `optionals`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but it's not was I looking for. I was trying to understand specifics of implementation

Comment: Specifics about how `argparse` implements the parsing, or how you should link two arguments via a custom action?

Comment: I've added an example of interacting action classes taken from the `argparse` unittest.  Maybe it will give you ideas of how to implement such a pair yourself.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for