# Python argparse dependence of arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have two arguments: --1st and --2nd
I'm trying to make "-2nd" argument required only if "1st" argument set.

For example:

If "1st" is set and "2nd" is set - good

If "1st" is not set and "2nd" is not set - good

Other cases are bad. Help me, please

Comment: Are both arguments optional? or is only the second optional?

Comment: Both optional. But if 1st set, 2nd is required. If 2nn set, first is required. In other cases there must be an error

Comment: I would make them both optional in argparse, then write my own code for validation checks on the results of calling `parse_args`.

Comment: Sounds like both are always required? If so, just use a single argument which consumes two values.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879657/argparse-argument-dependency

Comment: Probably a duplicate. Not going to close with the dupehammer just because the accepted answer there is mine. Anyway: I concur with myself from 2014: just use a single argument that eventually takes two values using `nargs=2`... much easier then having two distinct options that are actually just a single option.

Comment: There is a prioblem, I can't use single option. It's my task to use two distinct options. Also I mast use argparse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Kabanus' solution. Here is another one, which is simpler for new user:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--first')
parser.add_argument('--second')
options = parser.parse_args()

# Error checking
if (options.first is None) != (options.second is None):
    print 'Error: --first and --second must both be supplied or omitted'
```

## Discussion

- I don't use `--1st` and `--2nd` since `options.1st` does not work and `getattr(options, '1st') is too messy. Instead, I use`--first`and`--second` for illustration purpose.
- The expression `(options.first is None) != (options.second is None)` expressed your error condition succinctly.

Comment: You could still use `--1st` as the command line name if you provided a `dest='first'` for a useful Python attribute name.

Comment: `parser.error('--first and --second must both be supplied or omitted')` for a more consistent error message